# How to create Models in Django that act like a CMS?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, content-management-system

I need help developing models in Django's ORM that would give me the ability to create a user profile and then create unique pages under that user. What I am thinking so far is that I have one model called users and then another model pages. When the user is created and that user creates a page the data in both models are linked by a unique id. Is this the right direction to go or is there a more standard way of doing something like this? Essentially, what I am trying to create is a really stripped down version of Wordpress if that helps.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend trying an approach and then post that approach here when (if) you get stuck. In short, I'm sure there are multiple ways to do what you want. Perhaps start out trying your idea and see what happens.

Comment: I found out that using `ForeignKey` was exactly what I needed.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models